# IE createRange().pasteHTML pastes to top of page if nothing is selected

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am trying to get IE to paste to the current caret position in a contenteditable div. IE will paste fine if you have some text selected but if you have nothing selected it pastes your text to the top of the page. Is there a way to have it paste to the caret position instead of the top of the page?

```
<div id='ce' contenteditable='true'>select me...</div>
```

```
document.getElementById("insert").onclick = function() {
    document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML("-PASTED HTML-");
};
```

[fiddle (remember, IE only)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sx2Lt/3/)

Comment: i'm not sure if it is duplicate but I found the answer. myTextArea.focus(); http://jsfiddle.net/Sx2Lt/4/

Comment: You should post that as an answer and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turned out to be .focus on the text area. The actual scenario used the body element instead of a textarea and document.body.focus() worked for that situation.

Here is the fixed fiddle for this question:  jsfiddle.net/Sx2Lt/4 (IE ONLY)